# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver executable. というエラーが発生します

Tags: ruby, macos, google-chrome, selenium

MacOS-X、SeleniumをRubyで書いてChromeを動かそうとしているのですが、うまくいきません。RubyとSeleniumのインストールまではうまくいったのですが、ChromeDriverのインストールでハマっています。
具体的には、irbで

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :Chrome
```

とやっても

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:20:in `executable_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

と怒られてしまいます。

ネットでもいろいろ調べてみたのですがうまくいきません。
Chromedriverは

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/
```

に置いてあり、.bashrcにこのディレクトリへのパスも記述してあります。

あと何がいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: chromedriverを探しに行ってるということは、実際のコードでは正しく記述されてると思うのですが `Selenium::WebDriver.for :Chrome` の `:chrome`は小文字です。

Answer (score 1):

Selenium + Chromeで動かしたことはないのですが、同様の問題が発生するかどうかを確認してみました。
結果としては僕の環境では正常に動きました。

動作確認用のプログラムを作ってみたので、これを実行した結果を教えてください。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/selenium-chrome-sandbox

### 実行方法

```
git clone git@github.com:JunichiIto/selenium-chrome-sandbox.git
cd selenium-chrome-sandbox
bundle install
# 動作確認プログラム内のchromedriverをロードする場合
PATH=$PATH:./bin bundle exec ruby ./chrome.rb
# システムのPATHに存在するchromedriverをロードする場合
bundle exec ruby ./chrome.rb
```

### 正常に読み込めた場合の実行結果

```
start
Checking /usr/local/sbin/chromedriver, Exists?=false, executable?=false
Checking /usr/local/bin/chromedriver, Exists?=false, executable?=false
.
.
.
Checking ./bin/chromedriver, Exists?=true, executable?=true
FOUND ./bin/chromedriver
done
```

### 読み込めなかった場合の実行結果

```
start
Checking /usr/local/sbin/chromedriver, Exists?=false, executable?=false
Checking /usr/local/bin/chromedriver, Exists?=false, executable?=false
.
.
.
Checking /sbin/chromedriver, Exists?=false, executable?=false
NOT FOUND!!
/Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:20:in `executable_path': Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
        from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'
        from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
        from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
        from /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from ./chrome.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

### 参考

`find_binary`メソッドはselenium-webdriverで使われているロジックをそのまま移植したものです。
`find_binary`メソッドではPATHで取得した全ディレクトリに対して chromedriver という名前の実行可能ファイルがないかチェックし、見つかった時点でそのパスを返す、見つからなければ`nil`を返す、というロジックになっています。

```
# See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb#138
def find_binary(*binary_names)
  paths = ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)

  binary_names.each do |binary_name|
    paths.each do |path|
      exe = File.join(path, binary_name)
      puts "Checking #{exe}, Exists?=#{File.exist?(exe)}, executable?=#{File.executable?(exe)}"
      return exe if File.executable?(exe)
    end
  end

  nil
end

# See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb#19
path = find_binary "chromedriver"
```

Answer (score 1):

ターミナルで chromedriver にパスが通っているか確認してみてください。
以下は私のmacの環境です。chromedriver を /usr/local/bin にインストールしています。

```
$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

$ chromedriver --help
Usage: chromedriver [OPTIONS]

Options
  --port=PORT                     port to listen on
  --adb-port=PORT                 adb server port
  --log-path=FILE                 write server log to file instead of stderr, increases log level to INFO
  --verbose                       log verbosely
  --silent                        log nothing
  --url-base                      base URL path prefix for commands, e.g. wd/url
  --port-server                   address of server to contact for reserving a port
```

パスが通っている所にインストールされていないようでしたら、エラーメッセージにある以下のURLからダウンロードして、インストールしてください。

```
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

それと、アプリケーションフォルダにChromeがインストール済である必要があります。

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```